# How to write unit test for Ebean in play framework

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, ebean

I have an application based on play framework scala version 2.11.1. 
There are couple of methods for which I want to add unit tests. These methods have direct calls to database through Ebean.

I tried with this [link](https://ebean.io/docs/setup/testing) to use mocki-ebean in order to mock these calls. But the import was unsuccessful

I tried with powermock as well. but it requires to setup in-memory ebean server for mock calls. But that is also deprecated to setup in-memory server for unit testing.

Any idea what could be the next direction?